Anaconda Navigator not launching "Attribute error: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get' message pops up
I unistalled anaconda 5.0 and then installed 6.0. (this was an attempt to reset to standard packaged). Version 6.0 navigator opened up fine the first time.  The second time I opened it I get the error in the title and then a list of errors.  I've tried 'update conda' and I get the below error report that matches the list on start up as well
When I run updates as suggested in here I get errors
ERROR REPORT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(removedname)\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users\(removedname)\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 54, in main_subshell
    parser = generate_parser(add_help=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\(removedname)\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 127, in generate_parser
    configure_parser_plugins(sub_parsers)

  File "C:\Users\(removedname)\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 354, in configure_parser_plugins
    else set(find_commands()).difference(plugin_subcommands)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\(removedname)\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\find_commands.py", line 71, in find_commands
    for entry in os.scandir(dir_path):
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\C:\\WINDOWS\\system32'

Installed Anaconda 6.0 and cannot open navigator
